# AJAX call never ends

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call on my index.php page that displays contents spit out by a controller. It sends information an a link click to itself and the content is displayed, the content is a list of the directories and files. It works great on the first click and shows the contents of the directory you clicked but when I click on the newly created link to show its content it runs forever and does not stop. Is there something wrong with my AJAX?

here is the AJAX it sends a couple variables each time:

```
<script>
    var parent_dirs = "";
    var click_count = 0;

    jQuery('.container').on('click', '.show_content', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert('called');
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        parent_dirs += jQuery(this).attr('id');
        click_count++;

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : "/",
            type: "POST",
            data : { link: href, parent: parent_dirs, click_count: click_count },
            success: function(data)
            {
                var result = jQuery(data).find('.content_result');    
                jQuery('.container').append(result);
            },
            error: function(thrownError)
            {
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the index.php page I can not figure out why it runs nonstop. I figured it would just update the $_POST variables below and would run like before:

```
include "../app/bootstrap.php";
include "../src/controllers/DisplayContentsController.php";

$link = (isset($_POST['link']) ? $_POST['link'] : null);
$parent = (isset($_POST['parent']) ? $_POST['parent'] : null);
$click_count = (isset($_POST['click_count']) ? $_POST['click_count'] : null);

if ($link != null)
{
    if($click_count == 1)
    {
        $full_path = $starting_file_path . '/' . $parent . $link;
    }
    else
    {
        $full_path = $starting_file_path . '/' . $link;
    }

    DisplayContentsController::show($twig, $starting_file_path . '/' . $link);
}
else
{
    DisplayContentsController::show($twig, $starting_file_path);
}
```

Comment: The problem is server-side, and there isn't enough code or information to help you.  Try to narrow the problem down by commenting out sections of code until you figure out where the issue is.

Comment: As variant, try add timeout in your $.ajax

Example:
$.ajax({
url: '...',
//come code,
timeout: 15000
})